# panel with null layout draws blank panel

Tags: java, swingx

i am making a chat software. In this for each friend i am making a separate Panel containing his name and profile photo, this panel is having null layout . but problem here is that when the layout is set to null then it creates an empty panel(blank) even though i am setting bounds of each and every component that i placed over it. but as i change the layout to any other layout then it shows components over it.i have read many similar questions on stack community but there they have suggested to not to null layout but to get desired layout i have to use it use .so can anybody please help me in this.
 Below is the code for it: (here jpanel_friendy is variable whos e value i have initialized earlier.)

```
jpanel_friend[i]= new JPanel();                     
    jpanel_friend[i].setLayout(null);                                                                           
    jlabel_frienddp[i]=new JLabel();
    jlabel_frienddp[i].setIcon(dp);                 
    jlabel_friendname[i]= new JLabel(name);
    jlabel_friendname[i].setOpaque(true);
    jlabel_frienddp[i].setBounds(10,(jpanel_friendy+10),50,50);     
    jlabel_friendname [i].setBounds(70,(jpanel_friendy+10),70,50 );     
    jpanel_friend[i].setBounds(0,jpanel_friendy,250,200);           
    jpanel_friend[i].add(jlabel_frienddp[i]);               
    jpanel_friend[i].add(jlabel_friendname[i]);             
    jpanel_friendlist.add(jpanel_friend[i]);                
    i++;                                    
    friendcount++;                              
    jpanel_friendy = jpanel_friendy+60;
```